# Store stored procedure return value inside a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL, and I'm trying to store the return value of a stored procedure in a variable. But I'm getting a syntax error:

```
SET @MYVARIABLE = (EXEC [SP_MYSTOREDPROC] @PARAMETER1)
```

And the error states:

```
Incorrect syntax near keyword 'EXEC'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Useful hint: If you want to see how to execute a SP with a return, right click it in SSMS and execute. It generates the SQL for you and you can see that the answer below is the right syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to execute the procedure like this

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE INT
EXEC @MYVARIABLE = [SP_MYSTOREDPROC] @PARAMETER1
```

Answer (score 3):

run `exec sp_helptext 'SP_MYSTOREDPROC'`

check if there is a variable with `OUTPUT` clause then you would need to execute this procedure something like

### OUTPUT Param

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE  [DataType]
EXEC [SP_MYSTOREDPROC] @PARAMETER1, @MYVARIABLE  OUTPUT
```

If there isn't any variable with OUTPUT keyword then this Procedure is returning values for that you would do something like

### Return Param

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE  [INT]  --<-- Return Param are always INT type
EXEC @MYVARIABLE   = [SP_MYSTOREDPROC] @PARAMETER1
```